# cumulative distribution of sum of random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, convolution, density-function

Let $X, Y$ be two continuous indipendent random variables with cumulative distribution function $F_X(x)$ and $F_Y(x)$ respectively, and denote with $F_{X+Y}(x)$ the cumulative distribution of the sum $X+Y$. Is there a general inequality to relate the sum $F_X(x)+F_Y(x)$ (or the product $F_X(x) F_Y(x)$) with $F_{X+Y}(x)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. $F_{X+Y}(x)$ can be expressed by $F_X$ and $F_Y$:
$$ F_{X+Y}(x) =  \int_{-\infty}^\infty dz \; F_X(x-z) \frac{d}{dz}F_Y(z) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty dz \; \Big(\frac{d}{dz}F_X(z)\Big) F_Y(x-z) $$
but it depends onother values than just $F_X(x)$ and $F_Y(x)$, so in general a relation does not exist.

However, in some special cases, some relation may exist. For example, if $X$ and $Y$ have only posivite values (that is $F_X(z)=F_Y(z)=0$ for $z<0$), then you have 
$$ F_{X+Y}(x) =  \int_{0}^\infty dz \; F_X(x-z) \frac{d}{dz}F_Y(z) \le \int_{0}^\infty dz \; F_X(x) \frac{d}{dz}F_Y(z) = F_X(x)F_Y(x)$$

Comment: What if we assume that the underlying densities of $X$ and $Y$ are even functions?

Comment: It doesn't help. I was only able to obtain the relation because for all $z<0$ i had $\rho_Y(z) = 0$, because of that I could limit myself to $z>0$ for which $F_X(x-z)\le F_X(x)$. However, I just noticed that it is enough that one of variables is positive (in my example $Y$). The other may have negative values.

Answer (score 0):

The pdf of a sum is the convolution of the individual pdf's.

Hence in the Fourier or Laplace domain, the ordinary product.